# UITextView throws exception when binding to ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I've added a linkerPleaseInclude with no luck.

Below is some of the code I currently have implemented, I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong.

The following line throws an exception when binding.

```
        this.CreateBinding(MyTextView).For(v => v.Text).To<MyViewModel>(vm => vm.QuestionText).Apply();
```

Heres the Property Declaration in the view

```
          MyTextView = new UITextView(new CGRect(0, 0, myWidth, 105))
        {
            TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
            TextColor = UIColor.Black,
            Font = UIFont.FromName("Avenir-Heavy", 15f),
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left,
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
            //Alpha = .3f,
            ScrollEnabled = true,
            Editable = false,
            IndicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle.White
        };
```

Heres the Property Declaration in the ViewModel

```
string _questionText;
public string QuestionText
{
  get { return _questionText; }
  set
  {
    _questionText = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => QuestionText);
  }
 }
```

This is the Exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: missing source
>   event info in MvxWeakEventSubscription Parameter name: sourceEventInfo
>   at
>   MvvmCross.Platform.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`2[TSource,TEventArgs]..ctor
>   (UIKit.NSTextStorage source, System.Reflection.EventInfo
>   sourceEventInfo, System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs] targetEventHandler)
>   [0x00017] in <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Platform.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`2[TSource,TEventArgs]..ctor
>   (UIKit.NSTextStorage source, System.String sourceEventName,
>   System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs] targetEventHandler) [0x00012] in
>   <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Platform.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods.WeakSubscribe[TSource,TEventArgs]
>   (TSource source, System.String eventName,
>   System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs] eventHandler) [0x00000] in
>   <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Binding.iOS.Target.MvxUITextViewTextTargetBinding.SubscribeToEvents
>   () [0x00053] in <614c9ef828c14ba687a40ec2656f480f>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.CreateTargetBinding
>   (System.Object target) [0x00057] in
>   <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding..ctor
>   (MvvmCross.Binding.MvxBindingRequest bindingRequest) [0x0002f] in
>   <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Binding.Binders.MvxFromTextBinder.BindSingle
>   (MvvmCross.Binding.MvxBindingRequest bindingRequest) [0x00000] in
>   <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Binding.Binders.MvxFromTextBinder+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Bind>b__0
>   (MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBindingDescription description)
>   [0x00018] in <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext
>   () [0x0003a] in <8bc31b0df50a4d32b3f1d5af764165ad>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.AddBindings
>   (MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.IMvxBindingContextOwner view,
>   System.Object target, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T]
>   bindings, System.Object clearKey) [0x0001d] in
>   <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.AddBindings
>   (MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.IMvxBindingContextOwner view,
>   System.Object target, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T]
>   bindingDescriptions, System.Object clearKey) [0x00018] in
>   <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.AddBinding
>   (MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.IMvxBindingContextOwner view,
>   System.Object target, MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBindingDescription
>   bindingDescription, System.Object clearKey) [0x0000b] in
>   <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBaseFluentBindingDescription`1[TTarget].Apply
>   () [0x0001f] in <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0    at
>   BALAHA.iOS.Views.RecordingView.SetupBindings () [0x00418] in
>   /Users/BALAHA_mbp/Projects/BALAHA/BALAHA/iOS/Views/RecordingView.cs:799
>   at BALAHA.iOS.Views.RecordingView.ViewDidLoad () [0x0002f] in
>   /Users/BALAHA_mbp/Projects/BALAHA/BALAHA/iOS/Views/RecordingView.cs:114
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain
>   (int,string[],intptr,intptr)   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main
>   (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr
>   delegate) [0x00005] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/f70a1348/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
>   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String
>   principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/f70a1348/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
>   at BALAHA.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in
>   /Users/BALAHA_mbp/Projects/BALAHA/BALAHA/iOS/Main.cs:17  2018-01-12
>   18:23:28.985 BALAHA.iOS[888:372317] Unhandled managed exception:
>   missing source event info in MvxWeakEventSubscription

Comment: What exception.

Comment: im adding it @AdamBrown, see updated Post

Comment: What's `myTextView` here? Should rather be `questionTextView`?

Comment: @AdricoM it was a typo

Comment: could you post some other piece of code please? Useful informations would be: where is this code called (contructor, ViewDidLoad) ? Is it a list item or a control in a simple UIView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Correct way to implement this solution does not work for me I had to do the following:

In the View:

```
string _viewModelText;
    public string ViewModelText
    {
        get { return _viewModelText; }
        set
        {
            _viewModelText = value;

            if (_viewModelText != null)
            {
                MyTextView.Text = _viewModelText;
            }
        }
    }

    this.CreateBinding(this).For(v => v.ViewModelText).To<MyViewModel>(vm => vm.QuestionText).OneWay().Apply();
```

This solves the problem although its a roundabout way it gets the job done.

*UPDATE*

Although the method above works the reason for the original exception was the improper use of the ViewModel's Property.

The ViewModel's Property should be implemented as follows:

```
    string _questionText;
    public string QuestionText
    {
        get { return _questionText; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _questionText, value); }
    }
```

You can then bind the Textview's text property as such:

```
    this.CreateBinding(MyTextView).For(v => v.Text).To<MyViewModel>(vm => vm.QuestionText).Apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to LinkerPleaseInclude solved my problem:

```
public void Include(UITextView textView)
{
    textView.Text = textView.Text + "";            
    textView.Changed += (sender, args) => { textView.Text = ""; };            
    textView.TextStorage.DidProcessEditing += (sender, e) => textView.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error message it seems that the issue is caused by the linker. It seems you don't include a `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` file in your Xamarin.iOS project. See other similar questions [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/2527), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139534/textinputedittext-argumentnullexception-missing-source-event-info-in-mvxweakev) or [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/498).

During linking process, Xamarin.iOS strips out of the binary everything that is unused. This means that the fields and properties that are never accessed will not be visible for reflection. An example of `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` can be [found here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/f9f6e2643d2defc6ccc033f899a8ecf599441e67/TestProjects/Forms/Example001CSharp/Example.iOS/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs). It contains the most commonly used controls and their properties, but you can add your methods that will just touch the properties you don't want to lose during linking.

Comment: As the first line in my post states, " I have added a LinkerPleaseInclude with no luck"

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the line where you create the binding to see if `MyTextView` or `ViewModel` isn't null?

Comment: Neither are null at the time of the call to binding. I've done this before in another project, and even copied over the same code and still get the same error.